# Lost Passwords For McAfee Encrypted CDs

Tags: decryption

I have several CDs with emails from my last job.  The CDs were encrypted using McAfee and my logbook with the recorded password(s) is nowhere to be found.  What can I do to get my data?

Comment: Nothing; The files are encrypted. Without the password you have no way to decrypt the files. You could try to brute force the decryption process, but I seriously doubt, a commercial product wouldn’t be hardened against an attack like that.

Comment: [simplifying somewhat] The whole thing about encryption is that it can *always* be brute forced… eventually …but the security of the keys always remains beyond current technology's ability to brute force it in a reasonable time frame. Secure is years, very secure is centuries.

Answer (score 5):

In general without proper credentials it is impossible to break 'modern' encryption. This is actually the purpose of encryption.